# Cannot start ubuntu 16.04 after update and lots of fix attempts

Tags: kernel, boot-repair

I have tried fixing as much as possible as I have gone along after having "panic" errors and boot-repair didn't work. Not sure if it made things worse but it didn't work.

I am now getting this:

```
[ 1.016844] [drm:fw_domains_get [1915]] *ERROR* render: timed out waiting for
 forcewake ack to clear.
[ 1.596489] [drm:intel_set_pch_fifo_underrun_reporting [1915]] *ERROR* uncleared pch 
  fifo underrun on pch transcoder A
UBUNTU_13.04: clean, 596932/2932736 files, 4028819/11718656 blocks
[ 5.467729] LVM: Failed to initialize library context for activation generator.

Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "^D to 
try again to boot into default mode.

Give root password for maintenance (or press Ctrl-D to continue):
```

Of course I don't have a root password, I normally log in with my admin account then just sudo su to work as root.

I can go in with a boot usb and repair files that way, and have done so a few times.

Perhaps I should reinstall ubuntu. And as my own files are on /home which is mounted on sda6 and the system is on sda2, I assume those would not be lost (but obviously I back them up anyway). Also I might want to back up what is in /usr/ as that is normally stuff I have installed (although obviously I could reinstall them all. It only took a day or two last time).

I went into Recovery Mode. I got these errors:

```
Failed to start Activation of LVM2 logical volumes
See 'systemctl status lvm2-activation-early.service' for details
```

(How am I supposed to view that file?)

Also asked me to look at other lvm2-activation files for more things that failed.

Comment: Previously when I started up it asked me whether I wanted the label 13_04 or 12_04 and 13_04 which is clearly sda2 was giving me Panic Error. Now I cannot see that label and nothing works at all. It is still clearly visible. I want to restore it so I can use this install.

Comment: Note: after going through recovery then continuing to boot, it actually did do so. And I could get to my files. And at least back them up.

My system is not working perfectly but it is there.

If I did a reinstall on sda2, my /home is actually on sda6. Does that mean it won't affect those files at all?

Obviously there would be a need to install a load more programs but at least all my files would be safe. (They are also backed up).

Comment: well bit by bit I appeared to repair. I did a repair of gnome and also just got a compiz crash but hopefully that fixed itself and now it's just working.